# SSH Connection issue after migrating to new server

Tags: ssh

We have a client server (out of network) we connect to SFTP a file. It was working fine on Server1 until last week. Recently we migrated our application to Server2 (both server 1 and 2 are Linux).

Now we are not able to connect to client server from Server2. We have a SSH key (no password), key says `rsa_id_client.pub`. We copied the key from the old server to the new server, but it fails to authenticate with the key.

Are there any specific steps we have to follow in order to copy the key from old server to new server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Background

I typically will use `ssh-copy-id` to copy the public portion of an SSH key from a server to a client where I want to SSH/SFTP to. I would pay special attention to the permissions on the file when you copied it to Server2. The permissions on the file a important as well, if they're too wide open, SSH may refuse to use them.

```
$ ls -l ~/.ssh
-rw------- 1 sming staff   3326 Sep 24  2018 ssh_sm@id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 sming staff    737 Sep 24  2018 ssh_sm@id_rsa.pub
```

Here I have both my private key file (`ssh_sm@id_rsa`) and its corresponding public key file (`ssh_sm@id_rsa.pub`). To SSH from Server1 or Server2 you need to have your `ssh_sm@id_rsa` file local to the `~/.ssh` directory of the user you're attempting to SSH as.

On the remote clients you want to have the contents of your `ssh_sm@id_rsa.pub` file copied to a user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the client server.

That file's permissions should also be 600.

#### Tip

To facilitate all this I typically use the `ssh-copy-id` tool to properly manage the contents of the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file like so:

```
server2$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/ssh_sm@id_rsa someuser@client1
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did exactly the way you mentioned. But when I execute the ssh-copy-id command, it is able to get the corresponding keys. But it is also asking for password. I don't have any password. What should I do for this?

Comment: You'll need a password the 1st time you connect to the remote server.

Comment: What password should I give?

Comment: @user12132957 - the password of the account on the client1. Do you have some other method of SSH'ing to client1?

Comment: We are not using the pwd, this is SSH Key without password

Comment: @user12132957 - when I say password here I mean the one on the unix account on the client1 node, not the passphrase of the SSH key itself.